# hide GUI that briefly spawns when running a process from the command line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, gui, arduino

I'm running a build command on Ubuntu 12.04.  The command opens a GUI for a few seconds, and then closes it.  I'm finding this kind of disruptive -- is there a way to alter the command-line syntax to hide the GUI or pipe it elsewhere?

Specifically, I'm using Arduino 1.5.2's new command-line support:

```
arduino --verify /home/matt/blink/blink.ino
```

This pops up the standard Arduino IDE to perform the build or upload.

Comment: There's probably a horrendously complicated way of achieving this involving multiple workspaces or display servers; but have you tried looking at the documentation for this program to see if there's a command-line 'no GUI' option?

Comment: @evilsoup unfortunately, the program doesn't seem to have any such option, according to these [docs](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.5-from-command-line).

Comment: Have you tried adding an ampersand (`&`) at the end of the command?  This works for some things...

Comment: @Seth regrettably, this did not work..thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

You need `Xvfb`, it creates a pseudo X Windows device.  To install it on Ubuntu do this:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

Then create a pseudo X display putting it in background

```
Xvfb :100 &
```

Set the display to the pseudo X display:

```
export DISPLAY=:100
```

And launch Arduino.